# Order by time_field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, sql-order-by

I have a database table called "bookings" which users can select the 'time_from' and 'time_to' in which they want the booking done.

When adding these fields to the database I added them as a time_field.

```
<%= f.label :time_from, "From (24hr Clock)" %>
<%= f.time_field :time_from %>

<%= f.label :time_to, "To (24hr Clock)" %>
<%= f.time_field :time_to %>
```

The form works and saves correctly but my problem is the order. Below is my controller code and subsequently my view to display the time and its output. Any idea on how to order these by time correctly?

**Controller:**

```
def show
    @location = Location.find(params[:id])
    @booking = Booking.order("time_to")
    @company = Company.all
end
```

**View:**

```
<% 0.upto(11.to_i).each do |day_count| %>
    <span class="col-md-3 booking-times">
        <h4><%= time_tag(Date.today + day_count.days) %></h4>
        <span class="label label-danger no-bookings">No Bookings</span>
        <% @booking.each do |b| %>
            <% if b.date == Date.today + day_count.days && b.type == "Meeting" %>
                <% if b.location == params[:id] %>
            <span class="label label-info booking-time">
                <%= time_tag(b.time_from, :format=>"%H:%M") %> -
                <%= time_tag(b.time_to, :format=>"%H:%M") %>
            </span>
                    <% @company.each do |c| %>
                        <% if c.id == b.company %>
                            <%=link_to c.name, c %></br>
                        <% end %>
                    <% end %>
                <% end %>
            <% end %>
        <% end %>
    </span>
<% end %>
```

**Output: (For first day time)**

```
09:30 - 10:30
22:00 - 23:00
07:30 - 08:30
```

I appreciate this is not the nicest looking code. I would like the above output to order by time. Any ideas? I have tried to order in the controller, this effects the layout but not in the correct order still. I think the dat attatched to the time_to input may be having ian affect? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this:

```
@booking = Booking.order(time_to: :desc)
```

Comment: Tried that now and i am getting _some_ progress. It has just swapped the first (09:30) and third (07:30) output around.

Comment: Sure that those time_to don't refers to different days?
Beware that the order is done at SQL layer: have a look at the logs or try it in console to see the actual query...

Comment: I'm pretty sure? This is the logs output `Booking Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "bookings".* FROM "bookings" ORDER BY "bookings"."time_to" DESC`

Comment: The danger we have is it's treating the time as a pure number (like JS) -- what's the column type?

Comment: The column type was saves as :time_field. Is there a way to save time ONLY without an attatched date?

Comment: Okay, that's cool. What about your DB? I'm surmising it's `datetime`?

Comment: @RichPeck it is saved as time_field would it be better to have used datetime?

Answer (score 1):

Can you please try this:

```
@booking = Booking.order('time_to desc')
```

Comment: Thanks but no change on the above answer

Comment: Yes exactly hence no change.

Comment: Yes, when this is also correct answer then why -1. There is always one or more  way to give answer. By the way Thanks

Comment: I do realise that. I never gave you the negative vote? Thanks for your contribution though. I have +1 for you to take you back to 0.